# ipvlan access for docker daemon

Tags: docker

Currently I'm using next approach for assigning static ips to docker containers: I create ip alias for each such container and run them as:
`docker run -p <alias>:<port>:<port>`
And if I want to migrate container to different host I:

- stop container on host 1
- remove ip alias on host 1
- reload network on host 1
- add ip alias on host 2
- reload network on host 2
- start container on host 2

Which is not the most elegant solution and cannot be achieved by just docker client. Also there is docker-proxy process for each such port.

I'm trying to use ipvlan `docker run --net=<net> --ip=<ip>` and it works very well until you need access from host to container - for example when docker daemon needs access to registry which running in container. And all workarounds which I try to use looks ugly and unreliable. Is it possible to allow access to ipvlan containers for docker daemon (but better for everything) - something like having ipvlan address for host itself or compiling custom kernel with disabled host to ipvlan communication protection (I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with 4.15.0 kernel)?

Comment: It seems like it’d be vastly easier to set up a DNS service, have a host name per service, and not care about specific container IP addresses.  Then use can use ordinary `docker run -p` and the host IP addresses, and not mess with IP aliases or macvlan.  [Consul](https://consul.io) is a good building block if you want to build this by hand.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have dns server (also in docker container), but not everyone is able to use it (main dns server is not under my control and it is not easy and fast to modify records in it, also many vpn users don't have company dns at all). Also some containers need the same port.